# Flag Meaning: Off Topic -> Seeking Debugging Help

Tags: discussion, review-queues, flags

I recently did a review and flagged a post with the Off Topic / Seeking Debugging Help reason that was disputed.

From the description of the flag:

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must
>   include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the
>   shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.
>   Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other
>   readers.

The post in question is literally nothing more than a sentence saying the code isn't working nor reporting errors along with a code dump.  The code dump has an additional question in the middle where they ask "Is anything wrong with it?"  From my current understanding of the flag, this would be the perfect example of a post seeking debugging help.

Am I misunderstanding the nature of this flag, or were the other reviewers robo-reviewing?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you have a question about a flag or specific post, it helps to link to that post.* It seems you're talking about this one:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41992632/my-contact-form-is-not-working

It is, indeed, a code dump. Stripping out the code, the question was:

> I don't know why my contact form is not working. Here you have my form.
>
> It won't even report errors which is odd.
>
> *[snippet containing only a large HTML code blob]*
>
> And here you have  PHP code . Is anything wrong with it? What do you think? Please help me.
>
> *[large PHP code blob]*
>
> *[snippet containing only a JavaScript code blob]*

That is, indeed, pretty bad. It lacks a clear error message and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and the snippets can't do much, as one is HTML-only and one is JavaScript-only. So, your flag was correct.

The flag was automatically cleared, however, when the post [passed the Triage review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/15075820). The other reviewers there apparently weren't paying attention, so the vote was 3-1 "Looks OK." Those reviewers were wrong, though there's nothing you could have done about that.

---

* Yes, you do want to avoid the Meta effect, but it's best to at least give the content of the post in question. Or you can link and ask people to keep the Meta effect to a low level. We just need a little context!

Comment: I intentionally excluded the link in case my understanding was the problem at hand.  I didn't want to invoke the meta-effect in case I was wrong.  Thanks for looking!

Comment: @silencedmessage That's a fair point; see my edit above. *Some* Meta effect is pretty much unavoidable when you have questions about specific posts; otherwise, we just don't have enough info to answer.

Comment: Will do in the future.  Thanks for the example and feedback.